# Is There A Way to Have jQuery Point At A Variable url?

Tags: jquery

I'm made div buttons to select different pictures to go into a larger slot, kind of like an image carousel. I want the user to be able to enlarge the image but I've run into a problem, not knowing the languages well enough.

I'm working with jQuery for a variety of div button changes. Here is some example code as to how my div buttons work.

```
$('.change span').ready(function touch(e) {
        $('.change span').click(function touch(e) {
            $('.change span').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('.pic').css('background-image', $(this).attr("picChange"));
    });
});
```

This removes '.active' from all the buttons in the span, then adds '.active' to the span that was just click. It also finds a custom attribute found in the span HTML which says

```
picChange="url(http://....png)"
```

This places the image located in the url into the 'background-image' of the '.pic' div element.

So I don't have an href at the moment and I'm hoping there is a way to use jQuery to open a url. I can make another custom attribute that has info href would like but I don't understand the syntax to get href to accept a variable in jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean to use jQuery to open a URL? You want to redirect the user to another page? You want the dive with ".pic" class to act like a link when clicked on it? Can you give us more details please.

Comment: That’s right. I want to click directly on the div who’s css background = url(”http://....png”); the url leads to an image. So the background of the div looks like an image but that’s not in the html. I hope that makes sense. When they click the div I want it to take them to the page with the full sized image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. I got it. I spent a couple hours reading up on jQuery at https://learn.jquery.com

```
    $('.picholder').ready(function clickpicholder() {
        $('.picholder').click(function clickpicholder() {
            var woodselector = $(".activebtn").attr("hreff"); 
            window.open( woodselector );
        });
    });
```

```
<span class="btn1 activebtn" 
                    picChange="url(http://example.com/123.png)"
                    hreff="http://example.com/123.png"
                  //hreff is just a custom attribute//
```

The 2 things I needed to know were

1.) how to get and set elements (https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/)

2.) window.open() syntax. Which I learned like 6 different syntax that all supposedly work, but I tried 3 of them before finding one that worked.

I was using a variable called wood selector and it worked without any quotations, no '$' or '{}'. Just a plain variable name in the window.open()

So now when you click on my div element it summons a new page with the full sized image.